# 3 days before due date email reminder workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a due date field set, I want to send an email reminder 3 days before the due date to complete the form if the completed button radio button is set "No"...any guidance is highly appreciated.

I have access to Sharepoint 2007, 2013 and our Sharepoint 2013 is in the Cloud...

Comment: i need help to send email reminder with 90 day. i have a column that calculate 90 days requirement and i am trying to set a Workflow to send an email once the 90 day reminder day is reached but at the moment it is sending an email even if the date is greater than the 90 days [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJU1Y.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJU1Y.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Daniela, but i think i am doing that check my print screen...but i am not getting the result. it is still sending the email with the date being greater than 90 days(90 day reminder date) any idead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use a calculated column, just a standard workflow using the `Add Time to Date` actions.

[image]

I've been told that in 2013, if the Due Date is changed, the workflow will detect the change, so just run the workflow on create.

Comment: Ahh, I didnt know about the Add Time to Date function. Looks like this would work saving you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks Erin for this helpful info but should the statement be inside the IF statement not above?

Comment: It depends what you want. If you put it inside, it will check the value of Completed when the item is created, and from then on it won't matter whether someone marks it completed at a later time. So if that's your intended behavior, then go for it. However, if someone can create the item, but mark it complete in between then and the email date, then you want to leave it as I wrote it.

Comment: If the user  check a radiobutton  "not completed" then maybe forgot about the form, I want the email reminder, 3 days before due date, to send reminding user to complete the form.

Comment: Then keep it the way I have it.

Comment: If you, you can run a parallel action to end the workflow when completed is checked... that way you won't have every workflow running until 3 days before the due date. But I'd only bother with that if there are going to be thousands of items in this list and the due dates are months from the date of creation.

Comment: I never use parallel action so do you mind uploading a sample screen shot? It might be 50 list items per end of the month reporting.

Comment: 50's not a big deal. I wouldn't bother with the parallel step.  For future use, to add a parallel step, click in between the step boxes and use the insert action parallel step. Then, inside the step block, you can add regular steps. Google parallel steps if you get stuck.

Comment: Please help me understand pause until....will the pause not execute if current item: completed equal no line?

Comment: As I wrote it above, it will pause until 3 days before the due date. At that time, if `Completed = No`, it will send the email.

Comment: I set it up so it will send the email reminder within 12 hours before the due date but I notice it will send multiple email reminders every time the user edits the item. I guess the only way to avoid it is to set a column email reminder with checkbox so when checked...do not email again or do you know another way?

Comment: Do not run the workflow on edit. Only on create.

Comment: Not possible because there are other WF stages or steps that will fire during edits.

Comment: Then you need to have separate workflows.

Comment: Thank You much, @ErinL!

Answer (score 7):

I have seen many issues with long running workflows with pause until...
My recommendation, if it works for your scenario would be to use a the "Information Management Policy" to trigger a workflow on the Due Date -3.
The workflow would consist of only sending the email to the assigned person(s).  The IMP uses a timer job that "watches" for a date to fall within range and therefore is less resource intensive.

Example:
https://blog.splibrarian.com/2013/03/27/setting-up-automated-reminder-emails/

Comment: Great info. I will check the article and try it out as well after testing Erin's suggestion.

Comment: I've only had issues if there are a large number running for over a week, or if the workflows have a lot of stages and steps. But this answer is still probably the best practice approach.

Comment: Looks good, but how frequent does Retention Policy check the item? I try to play with minutes but nothing works. Does it check once per Day?..

Comment: It is controlled by 2 timer jobs, Expiration Timer Job and Information management Policy Timer Job.  I wouldn't recommend less than every 5 minutes.  More reading available here https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/tag/information-management-policy/

Comment: Hi, information management policy only allows Due Date + 3 and will not allow negative values there. How did you solve this issue? Did you have to create another column to store =[Due Date] - 3 value?

Comment: @Unnie Yes.  You have to have a column (it can be hidden) with the exact date you want the IMP to trigger

Answer (score 1):

My solution using a calculated column and a WF works as follows:

1. Create a calculated column named "ReminderDueDate" with the following calculation with its result as a **date**:

> =[Due Date]-3

2. Create a WF that runs on the creation of the item (if the due date is already there) or with the modification (if the Due Date is added later) and pause it until the "ReminderDueDate" column arrives (**Pause until date action**).

And it works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually using a completely different approach.
In stead of creating a workflow (which I have no experience in), I simply created a view with some conditions:

Status = Requested AND
Due date >= [Today] AND
Due date <= [Today]+3

This view will show all items that have status Requested and are due within the next 3 days.
Then simply add an alarm to the view, for any changes in the view, and you will receive an alarm about it.

Comment: I don't think this will work, unless the items are frequently modified.  The calculated column will not recalculate daily.  *Alerts* will not trigger 3 days before the due date.  For a view to work, you would need to train the workforce to check the list view daily.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure something like this would fit perfectly but may be a start. [image]

EDIT:

Where 'created' is equal to due date.

[image]

In the end if you set up a List Workflow in SharePoint Designer, using the appropriate library.

Use the buttons to select the correct values you will end up with a workflow like this whcih should sent it at the correct date.

[image]

Comment: This is a good start. Now if they change the list item, will the workflow run another instance in addition to the pause workflow?

Comment: If I am getting this correctly then: when the item is updated in the list the workflow will trigger and look at all the values again. So if you change the due date it will pick up and change when to unpause and send the emails.

Comment: The name of the field is Due Date but when I enter in the box Due Date -3, it is not retaining it.

Comment: This was written more as pesudo code so it may not be the correct format. A simple way around would be to create a hidden calculated column which takes the date in due date and takes 3 off (Its hidden so the user would not see this). Then use pause until on that value. I have added image to my answer showing the column to create.

Answer (score 0):

In 2013 you can create a workflow that functions just like a Timer Job. Just use a loop and a pause actions. Loop through the List items and check if Due Date - 3 = Today, if so send out an email. Out side of the loop pause for 24 hours and go back to the stage that checks for the due date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of workflow that send email 3 days before the due date.

[image: Dummy Workflow]